# Should I run the official php-fpm image with an init system to avoid the PID 1 problem?

Tags: php, docker

I read about docker and [the PID 1 problem](https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/01/20/docker-and-the-pid-1-zombie-reaping-problem/), and I am a bit paranoid now. I create my own image based on the official [php-fpm image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) and wonder if I should run an init system instead of php-fpm as PID 1.

How could I find out if a process works fine regarding signaling and reaping? Checking the docs did not answer this. Can I safely assume that official, popular docker images are just designed well in that regard?
Currently, I am just inclined to have run everything with [docker's built-in init system](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#init) due to my unsureness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running containers with `--init` is safe, and if you're at all worried about this class of problem, go ahead and do it.  (If you ever run containers in a context that's not pure Docker, note that [Kubernetes does not have an equivalent option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50803268/kubernetes-equivalent-of-docker-run-init) and you need to have an init process built into your image.)

In both of these cases, code inspection can help you figure out if there's even potentially a problem.  Do you ever launch a subprocess?  A typical Docker-packaged HTTP service doesn't.  If you don't, then a child process can never launch a grandchild process and then exit without cleaning it up, so you can never inherit an unexpected zombie child process.  Similarly, if you never launch a subprocess, then the only things that can send you signals are your own code and `docker stop`, and you can easily tell if there's a problem there.

None of the standard Docker Hub images I've looked at in detail run an init system.  Stack Overflow Docker questions seem to contain very few complaints about `docker stop` not working, or about processes leaking on the host.  I wouldn't especially worry about this, unless you have evidence to think you have a problem, or if you're trying to check absolutely every last "it's a good idea to..." box.